# ¿Cómo solucionar Error: Module Federation only works with Webpack 5 al intentar usar en el proyecto micro-frontend de Next.js 10?

Tags: webpack, next.js

Estoy tratando de desarrollar microfrontend en un proyecto NextJs 10 como se describe en https://gist.github.com/jherr/dd10bc34448590a2661a0c6acbcc7e8a/revisions. Pero cuando intento correrlo, tanto en mi proyecto como en el del ejemplo https://github.com/jherr/wp5-nextjs-10.git, aparece el siguiente error: `Error: Module Federation only works with Webpack 5`

[Error: Module Federation only works with Webpack 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsocf.png)

Estoy usando Windows 10 y mi versión de Node es v14.12.0

¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto, si se supone que cuando instalo las dependencias ya se deben instalar con la versión 5 de Webpack incluida?¿o es que estoy equivocado?